# JsonFormatter in WebApi is ignored

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I need to configure the JSON output of a Web API.

It works, when I directly set the JsonProperty-Attribute on properties.
But changes in the settings of the JsonFormatter (in the Register-method) are completely ignored.

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services   

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver  = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        // ...
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try like this - `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() 
{ 
NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include, ContractResolver  = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};`

Comment: setting the GlobalConfiguration is also ignored.

Comment: how do you pass "config" into Register function? new HttpConfiguration () ?

Comment: Register is called from the Application_Start in the Global.asax. 
-> GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

Answer (score 0):

My fault.

In the WebApi I talked to an Azure DocumentDB.

So I had - of course - configure the DocumentDB serializer to format the Json documents.

```
    static DocumentDbRepository()
    {


        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () =>
            {
                return new JsonSerializerSettings
                           {
                               NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                               TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,  

                               //serializing works, but Linq to DocumentDB provider seems to ignore the ContractResolver. -> [JsonProperty]
                               //ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                           };
            };


    }
```